# DTD - Is it possible to declare attribute for multiple element at once

Tags: xml, dtd

How to declare attributes for multiple elements?

Like:

```
<!ATTLIST foo,bar createdAt CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to define a parameter entity, which is essentially just a macro. This example defines two parameter entities, one of which references the other:

```
<!ENTITY % role.att
        'role                   NMTOKEN         #IMPLIED'>

<!ENTITY % common.att
        'id                     ID              #IMPLIED
        %role.att;'>

<!ATTLIST notice %common.att;>
```

When experts do this, the resulting DTDs become extremely complicated and almost unreadable to ordinary mortals, but the feature is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

With XML DTDs, this is only possible using parameter entities as Michael explained (cf. [the XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#attdecls)). OTOH, SGML DTDs allow attribute list declarations for multiple elements in a form very close to what you have in mind:

```
<!-- only valid in SGML rather than XML DTDs: -->
<!ATTLIST (elem1|elem2|elem3) myatt CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

SGML also allows *name groups* in place of a single name in other markup declarations.

Moreover, WebSGML (ISO 8879:1986/Cor 2:1999) also allows `#ALL` and `#IMPLICIT` in place of an element name to apply the declaration to all declared or implied elements, resp. These were included into WebSGML to represent generic XML attributes such as `xml:base`, `xml:lang` and `xmlns` (but not `xmlns:xyz`). However, just like the *name group* syntax, they didn't become part of the XML subset of SGML.